# Count duplicate cells (values, text & empty) when you compare two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two worksheets with the following data structures:

```
sheet a) Id   Name  abn  address    sheet b) Id  Name abn  address
         1    AA    123  ac                  25  ad   124  ab
         015  Ac    125  aw                  02  aa   123  ac
         26   3m         az                  8   aap  234  df
         32   im    98   op                  17  aj        aw
         230  aap   234  df                  15  3m   160  az
```

What I need to find is duplicate values from sheet b against sheet a.

I've tried `countif`, `match`, `vlookup`, and `index` functions,
but still I'm not happy with the result.
Need position because duplicate is repeated more than 3 times, find exact position id for that duplicate.  How do I find duplicate values from two different sheets?

Comment: Wait I'm confused, are you trying to find duplicate values, or locations or just the number of duplicates?

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  You show four columns, but no row in `sheet a` matches any row in `sheet b` in all four columns –– so, do you need to show them all?  Are you looking for ***all*** duplicate values, such as `a.Name[3]` = `3m` = `b.Name[5]`,  `a.Name[5]` = `aap` = `b.Name[3]`,  `a.Name[1]` = `AA` = `b.Name[2]` = `aa` (case insensitive),  `a.Id[2]` = `015` = `b.Id[5]` = `15` (ignore leading zeroes),  `a.abn[1]` = `123` = `b.abn[2]`,  `a.abn[3]` = (blank) = `b.abn[4]`,  and all the matches in the `address` column?  Or are you interested in only a single column?  … (continued)

Comment: (continued) …  If you’re interested in only a single column, (a) please say so, and (b) show that column first, with maybe one other to illustrate associated data –– don’t clutter the question with irrelevancy.  If you’re interested in more than one column, rephrase your question (title) –– “compare two worksheets”, maybe?  Show us what you want the result to look like.  Do you want to count, find position, or both?  What does the “3 times” have to do with the question?  Please give us at least one example of _exactly_ what you’ve tried and why you found it unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're okay with a few duplicates, but for any over 3, you want to see them.

I put together a UDF called "xMatch" that might help you out. It's just like Match, in that it returns the position of a value, but it lets you specify you want to find the *nth* value (e.g. the 3rd duplicate).

```
=xMatch("Look for", "Look in this column", "Find the nth one")
```

To make it work, you'll need to insert this code into a Module (I explain how below if you're unfamiliar):

```
Public Function xMatch(lookup_value As String, column_array As Range, find_nth As Integer)'

Dim aSize As Integer 'Rows in the column_array
Dim Hit() As Long 'Array that keeps track of all match locations
Dim i As Long 'Iterator
Dim z As Long 'Counts zeroes
Dim Pos As Integer 'Position of our desired match in the column array

aSize = column_array.Rows.Count
ReDim Hit(1 To aSize)

'Check each cell in the range for matches
'When a match is found, note it's postion in the Hit array
'If a match isn't found, add another zero to the count
For i = 1 To aSize
 If (InStr(1, column_array(i), lookup_value) > 0) Then
  Hit(i) = 1 * i
 Else
  z = z + 1
 End If
Next i

'Small finds the kth smallest number, but considers ties as seperate numbers
'Consider {1,0,0,2}
'1st smallest number is 0, and the second smallest number is also 0
'So we need to screen out the all the zeros (z) and then find the nth item after that
Pos = WorksheetFunction.Small(Hit, z + find_nth)

xMatch = Pos

End Function
```

In order to place this code, press **Alt** + **F11** from your Excel file, and it will open the VBA Editor. On the toolbar, select **Insert**, and select **Module**.

Open up the new Module and paste the code in!

Now when you type "=xMatch(" in a cell, it will let you use your new formula.

Hope this helps!